# How can I handle multiple audio?

Tags: android, audio, handler

I made a project where two textviews are on screen.I set two audio for the two textview with Ontouch method.So when i touch any of the textview it play the sound.
Here is the code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText1);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
"fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
"fonts/DroidSans.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(tf);
tv1.setTypeface(tf1);

tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText ))
           {
               MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.robotrock);
                mp.start();
       }  
       return false;  
   }
    return false;  
   }

       });  
 tv1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText1 ))
           {
               MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.nam);
            mp1.start();
           }
       }  
       return false;  
   }  

       });
  }}
```

That is how i did it.The problem is when i touch both the textview,both audio play at the same time.
But I want when i touch one textview ,the audio will play and at that time if i touch another ,the previous audio need to stop and play the corresponding audio which textview is touched.So how can i handle them?Where i need to implement or edit my code?

**Please HELP!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already created two instaces of media player. What you have to do is to check for which is playing and stop it.

```
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText ))
           {
               MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.robotrock);
               if (mp1 != null && mp1.isPlaying()) {
                   mp1.stop();
               }
                mp.start();
       }  
       return false;  
   }
    return false;  
   }

       });  
 tv1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText1 ))
           {
               MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.nam);
               if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                   mp.stop();
               }
            mp1.start();
           }
       }  
       return false;  
   }
```

Comment: I fix the problem.Here Media Player need to declared globally

Comment: yes otherwise you need to create it as final in that case you cannot recreate that object so it should be in class instead of function.

Answer (score 0):

Declare two mediaplayer instance globally and try this code

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.robotrock);
    mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.nam);


tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText ))
           {
               mp1.stop();
                mp.start();
       }  
       return false;  
   }
    return false;  
   }

       });  
 tv1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText1 ))
           {
            mp.stop();
            mp1.start();
           }
       }  
       return false;  
   }  

       });
  }}
```

i think this will solve the problem......

Comment: whats the error showing...just add the try catch for that code

Comment: No error.But the logic is not right.I use pause();It works like when i click tv play mp.and when i click tv1,mp is pause.But mp1 is not play.